# Most elegant way to calculate completion times for a list of jobs in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list of jobs in form of `[(weight, length)]`, e.g.

```
[(99, 1), (100, 3), (100, 3), (99, 2), (99, 2)]
```

But much larger.

And i've written a function that schedules them according to different keys that I pass as a parameter. This means that for each job I calculate its finishing time as a sum of all the previous jobs. The ultimate goal is to calculate the weighted finishing times: `weight[i] * completion_time[i]`

Currently I don't see an elegant way to do this without separating all the lengths in a separate list, which doesn't seem very Pythonic to me.

Here is the code

```
def schedule(jobs_list, sort_key):
     sorted_jobs = sorted(jobs_list, key=sort_key, reverse=True)
     lengths = [job[1] for job in sorted_jobs]
     weighted_completion_times = [sum(lengths[:i + 1]) * sorted_jobs[i][0] for i in range(len(sorted_jobs))]
     return sum(weighted_completion_times)
```

and here is the sample usage:

```
schedule(jobs, lambda t: (t[0] - t[1], t[0]))
```

Ideally I would like the solution to be both human-readable and memory efficient (i.e. without creating another list of lengths)

Comment: `... for i in range(len(...)) ...`

is often a code smell in Python, in which the preferred idiom is to iterate directly over a sequence of values rather than iterating over the indexed and then indexing the sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the [`itertools.accumulate()` iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to produce the acumulative weight of your lengths:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def schedule(jobs_list, sort_key):
     sorted_jobs = sorted(jobs_list, key=sort_key, reverse=True)
     acc_lengths = accumulate(job[1] for job in sorted_jobs)
     weighted_completion_times = (al * job[0] for al, job in zip(acc_lengths, sorted_jobs))
     return sum(weighted_completion_times)
```

Note that this at no point builds new lists other than the sorted list. Both by avoiding building intermediary lists as well as avoiding re-summing longer and longer sublists (making this O(N) vs your O(N^2) approach), the above is also much more efficient; just on your short sample there is a 25% improvement in timings:

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> def schedule_lists(jobs_list, sort_key):
...      sorted_jobs = sorted(jobs_list, key=sort_key, reverse=True)
...      lengths = [job[1] for job in sorted_jobs]
...      weighted_completion_times = [sum(lengths[:i + 1]) * sorted_jobs[i][0] for i in range(len(sorted_jobs))]
...      return sum(weighted_completion_times)
...
>>> def schedule_acc(jobs_list, sort_key):
...      sorted_jobs = sorted(jobs_list, key=sort_key, reverse=True)
...      acc_lengths = accumulate(job[1] for job in sorted_jobs)
...      weighted_completion_times = (al * job[0] for al, job in zip(acc_lengths, sorted_jobs))
...      return sum(weighted_completion_times)
...
>>> jobs = [(99, 1), (100, 3), (100, 3), (99, 2), (99, 2)]
>>> timeit('schedule(jobs, lambda t: (t[0] - t[1], t[0]))',
...        'from __main__ import jobs, schedule_lists as schedule',
...         number=100000)
0.6098654230008833
>>> timeit('schedule(jobs, lambda t: (t[0] - t[1], t[0]))',
           'from __main__ import jobs, schedule_acc as schedule',
...        number=100000)
0.4608557689934969
```

The difference is far more pronounced when you increase the job list size to 1000 however:

```
>>> import random
>>> jobs = [(random.randrange(80, 150), random.randrange(1, 10)) for _ in range(1000)]
>>> timeit('schedule(jobs, lambda t: (t[0] - t[1], t[0]))',
...        'from __main__ import jobs, schedule_lists as schedule',
...         number=1000)
5.421368871000595
>>> timeit('schedule(jobs, lambda t: (t[0] - t[1], t[0]))',
...        'from __main__ import jobs, schedule_acc as schedule',
...         number=1000)
0.7538741750176996
```

Comment: Wow! Indeed on the 20000 long lists your solution is nearly 10 times faster!